# Why won't IE8 render?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, rendering, aem

I'm helping build a site for a client in Adobe CQ5.  Due to the preferences of the client I cannot post the source, but we are having trouble with IE8.

When we try to view the site in IE8 the page will not render.  When using the dev tools we can browse the HTML and the select tool does successfully highlight elements with the blue outline, but none of them render.  The page is simply white.  Things render properly in IE7 browser mode but not in IE8 or IE8 Compatibility Mode.

I've run the html through the W3 validator and nothing egregious jumped out.  Anyone have any leads?

Comment: Could you please post the source or upload to a server so we can see?

Comment: If you don't post your code, it's unlikely that anyone will be able or willing to help you.

Comment: Without seeing any code it's blind guesswork. It's either HTML, CSS, or JS, or maybe server headers, or perhaps a broken JPG file. It really could be anywhere. Maybe there's something in the javascript console. Or the server log. Or a caching proxy. I've seen all of these things break page rendering in IE.

Answer (score 0):

there must be some javascript error which causing this. otherwise CQ5 render well in ie8

Answer (score 0):

If it works in IE7 but not IE8 you can try adding this to the `<head>` section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

This forces IE7 emulation. You can also try playing with the doctype to see if this makes any difference.